# notification channel min API level vs. target API level

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

In my app i have set min API level to 19 and target level to 26 (Oreo). Now, when I try to create a notification without a notification channel, it does not work because a notification channel is required when target API level is 26. But when I try to create the notification channel the IDE complains that creating a notification channel requires min API level 26.

How should I go about this? I would not want the set the minimum level to 26.

Comment: see an example here https://github.com/DimaKoz/Android-Foreground-Service-Example

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to set the minimum API level to 26. You can check the API level at runtime to conditionally call `createNotificationChannel` when the API level is equal to or greater than Android 8.0 (API level 26)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
        CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    notification = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle("title...")
        .setContentText("message...")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .build();
}
```